# Entity Framework 6.1 SaveChanges() -> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

Guys I'm out of ideas...

Info :

- WPF aplication (C#, .net Framework 4.5)
- EntityFramework 6.1
- Recreated whole model (even merged from 3 models to 1)
- Uninstalled/installed EntityFramework (console and nuget) few times
  :)

Everything works fine if I run it from VS, but when I run .exe (or ClickOnce) there is error... I have `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in my references, EF adds it on its own.¸I deleted/re added it on my own...still same.

I tried to set both copy localy to true and false, it even stops working in VS when i copy it localy.

**All Error info :**

Message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0,      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

Source:

```
EntityFramework
```

Trace:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildTypeValidator[T](Type clrType, IEnumerable`1 edmProperties, IEnumerable`1 navigationProperties, Func`3 validatorFactoryFunc)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidatorBuilder.BuildEntityValidator(InternalEntityEntry entityEntry)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationProvider.GetEntityValidator(InternalEntityEntry entityEntry)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetValidationResult(IDictionary`2 items)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   my function call
```

If you need any more info please ask.

Comment: use FusLogVw.exe  and turn on "failed bind". Then try your program and check the log... plenty of detail there. But looking at the error it is security related.

Comment: Look in the folder where it's running from. Verify that the file exists and then verify that it's the correct version. Usually the problem is that you're loading the file from another location on your PC or from the GAC, but when you deploy it, it doesn't exist at the deploy location, or it exists but is the wrong version.